# How to draw a ring inside another ring

Tags: android, xml, draw, geometry, ring

I have to present icons inside the circles, I tried to draw a ring inside an another ring but i cant to do, When i tried it is awkward position how can i do it

[image: I tried to do like this but i can't]

**My Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Larger blue circle in back -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#f00"/>
        <size
            android:width="15dp"
            android:height="15dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<!-- Smaller red circle in front -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <!-- transparent stroke = larger_circle_size - smaller_circle_size -->
        <stroke android:color="@android:color/transparent"
            android:width="10dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#fff"/>
        <size
            android:width="1dp"
            android:height="1dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <!-- transparent stroke = larger_circle_size - smaller_circle_size -->
        <stroke android:color="@android:color/transparent"
            android:width="11dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#f00"/>
        <size
            android:width="1dp"
            android:height="1dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: did you try with a `Canvas`? (without the xml, directly on the `Bitmap`)

Comment: No i didn't try try i used only xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:width="200dp"
                android:height="200dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke android:color="#ff0000" android:width="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:left="5dp"
        android:top="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:bottom="5dp">

        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke android:color="#5BB534" android:width="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try my code. You can rewrite the values as per your requirement.
When you add this drawable to any background, make sure that view is a square.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:left="6dip"
    android:right="6dip">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval">
        <stroke
            android:width="3dip"
            android:color="#f00" />
    </shape>

</item>

<item
    android:bottom="80dip"
    android:left="80dip"
    android:right="80dip"
    android:top="80dip">

    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <stroke
            android:width="1dip"
            android:color="#0f0" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

**Edit** Added Image
[image: This what I get.]

Comment: @Swathy : Updated with image

Answer (score 1):

Try to draw it with a Canvas:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) (15 * metrics.density), (int) (15 * metrics.density), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // 15dp x 15dp
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

// clear the bitmap with a transparent color
canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStrokeWidth(2 * metrics.density); // 2dp, the circle width

// the external circle, large as the bitmap
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);

// the internal one, smaller than the first one
paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2, bitmap.getWidth() / 2 - 3 * metrics.density, paint);
```

You should adjust some numbers. The `DisplayMetrics` is just used to transform sizes in dp (rather than pixels). Once finished you can use your `Bitmap` with a `BitmapDrawable` if you need to use it into a View (for example as background).

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:left="3dp"
    android:right="3dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <stroke android:width="5dp"
            android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark">

        </stroke>
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="10dp"
    android:left="10dp"
    android:right="10dp"
    android:top="10dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <stroke android:width="10dp"
            android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark">

        </stroke>
    </shape>
</item>
```